# Getting the App object returns a null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

The `getApp()` method is returning `null`. Any idea why?

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static App app;

    private BoxStore boxStore;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        app = this;

        boxStore = MyObjectBox.builder().androidContext(App.this).build();
        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        {
            new AndroidObjectBrowser(boxStore).start(this);
        }

    }

    public static App getApp() {
        return app;
    }

    public BoxStore getBoxStore() {
        return boxStore;
    }

}
```

The `getApp()` method is called from an Activity like below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BoxStore boxStore = App.getApp().getBoxStore();
    Box<ListEntryObject> listEntryObjectBox = boxStore.boxFor(ListEntryObject.class);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("TYPE_OF_ACTION", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("sourceToDest", 0);
    editor.apply();

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("POSITION" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("position", 0);
    editor.apply();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("TYPE_OF_ACTION", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            editor.putInt("sourceToDest", 0);
            editor.apply();

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            entryDialogFragment = new EntryDialogFragment();

            entryDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "Sample Fragment");

        }
    });

    entryObjectList = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Comment: post the code where you are calling this getApp method

Comment: you need to add your application class into your manifest file android:name
    The fully qualified name of an Application subclass implemented for the application. When the application process is started, this class is instantiated before any of the application's components.

    The subclass is optional; most applications won't need one. In the absence of a subclass, Android uses an instance of the base Application class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be sure to link this class (App ) to application tag in Manifest.xml as mentioned in below code

```
<application
    android:name="package.MyClass"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    ...
 </application>
```